# How make pretty url nextcloud

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nextcloud

This my nginx.conf

How change file for pretty url nextcloud.

How make url without index.php

http://mynextcloud.com/***index.php***/....
to
http://mynextcloud.com/....

```
location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
            #fix
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
            fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true; #Avoid sending the security headers twice
            fastcgi_pass backend;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        }
```